# python, apply function to dataframe indexed by id and timestamp on each feature column

Tags: python, pandas, multidimensional-array, filter, apply

Hi guys i have a dataframe with 5 columns:

ID (integer) | TIME (integer) | humidity | temperature | pressure

ID = room
TIME = unixtimestamp seconds
humidity/temperature/pressure = sensor values

what i need....

i want to execute a filter (signal.lfilter) on humidity/temperature/pressure by ID... for example...

for ID = 1
  execute lfilter at humidity values ordered by TIME asc
  execute lfilter at temperature values ordered by TIME asc
  execute lfilter at pressure values ordered by TIME asc

for ID = 2
  execute lfilter at humidity values ordered by TIME asc
  execute lfilter at temperature values ordered by TIME asc
  execute lfilter at pressure values ordered by TIME asc

...

for ID = n
  execute lfilter at humidity values ordered by TIME asc
  execute lfilter at temperature values ordered by TIME asc
  execute lfilter at pressure values ordered by TIME asc

how could i do this fast? today i'm using 2 for loops:

```
for i in df.id.unique():
    for column in ['humidity','temperature','pressure']:
        df[df.id=i][column] = ... lfilter ...
```

but it's too slow, any help?

Comment: You haven't given enough information to solve the problem.  Depending on what `lfilter` is, we might be able to do some really fast vectorization.  But you neglected to tell us what it is.  Try to follow the advice laid out here [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not super clean, but try the following. Is this the operation you're after with the `signal.lfilter` function?

Edit: Whoops, forgot about the time requirement. Just running `df.sort_values(['ID', 'TIME'], ascending=True)` before the operations below should do the trick.

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy import signal
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(1618)

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1,1,1,2,2,2], 
                   'humidity': np.random.random(6), 
                   'temperature': np.random.random(6), 
                   'pressure': np.random.random(6)})

#  >>> df
#     ID  humidity  pressure  temperature
#  0   1  0.605160  0.194984     0.450019
#  1   1  0.301108  0.077726     0.691227
#  2   1  0.197976  0.144978     0.155231
#  3   2  0.733884  0.458959     0.785704
#  4   2  0.457377  0.647681     0.092045
#  5   2  0.021497  0.417326     0.551941

tmp = df.groupby('ID').apply(lambda x: signal.lfilter(x['humidity'], x['pressure'], x['temperature']))
# this produces a vector for each ID.
# we have to unstack the vectors and append them to the original df

df['filtered']  = tmp.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x)).stack().reset_index()[0]

# >>> df
#    ID  humidity  pressure  temperature  filtered
# 0   1  0.605160  0.194984     0.450019  1.396696
# 1   1  0.301108  0.077726     0.691227  2.283506
# 2   1  0.197976  0.144978     0.155231  0.057383
# 3   2  0.733884  0.458959     0.785704  1.256354
# 4   2  0.457377  0.647681     0.092045 -0.842783
# 5   2  0.021497  0.417326     0.551941  1.058038
```